# If $h$ is an arbitrary holomorphic function then there exist $\phi_1, \phi_2$ holomorphic such that $h = f\phi_1 + g\phi_2$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, holomorphic-functions

I don't need this statement to be true globally - even if it's locally true I'm fine with that. I'm on a noncompact Riemann surface but that doesn't matter because I only want this to hold locally anyway, so we can just look at little subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. Say $h$ is an arbitrary holomorphic function.  Say $f,g$ are holomorphic functions with no common zero. Then I want to show that there exist $\phi_1, \phi_2$ holomorphic such that $h = f\phi_1 + g\phi_2$ *locally* (so on some neighbourhood of some fixed point). I'm happy to just work with Taylor series of all these functions (which is what I was doing) because as I said, I'm fine with this holding just locally. But I can't quite figure out how it works. I'd appreciate some help, please!

Comment: I may be missing something stupid, but: since you just want this locally around a point, say $z_0$, then if $f(z_0) \neq 0$ you can take $h = h/f \cdot f + 0 \cdot g$ and if $g(z_0) \neq 0$ you can take $h = 0 \cdot f + h/g \cdot g$...? Where you've shrunk the neighborhood enough so that either $f$ or $g$ does not vanish.

Comment: Thank you! While I'm happy for the equality to hold locally, I do want all my functions (including $\phi_1, \phi_2$) to be globally defined.

Comment: As in, globally defined and holomorphic

Comment: Actually no maybe I can't expect that; maybe that's asking for too much. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an advanced level but very general answer.
Let $X$ be a complex manifold (or even  complex space with singularities ) and let $f_1,\cdots, f_n\in \mathcal O(X)$ be globally defined holomorphic functions .
Then we have a an $\mathcal O_X$-linear map of coherent sheaves $$f=(f_1,\cdots, f_n):  \mathcal O_X^n\to  \mathcal O_X                 $$ sending $(\phi_1,\cdots, \phi_n)$ to $\sum f_i\phi_i$.
The hypothesis that the $f_i$'s have no common zero at any point $x\in X$ implies that this morphism of sheaves is surjective,  so that denoting by $\mathcal K$ its kernel we get the exact sequence of *coherent* sheaves $$0\to\mathcal K  \to\   \mathcal O_X^n\to  \mathcal O_X \to 0                $$ The long exact sequence of cohomology then yields the fragment $$\cdots              \to \mathcal O_X(X)^n\to  \mathcal O_X(X) \to H^1(X,\mathcal K)\to \cdots      $$ 
If $X$ is Stein, as is for example every non-compact Riemann surface, Cartan-Serre's Théorème B for coherent sheaves  implies that $H^1(X,\mathcal K)=0$, so that $$\mathcal O_X(X)^n\to  \mathcal O_X(X)\to 0$$ is surjective.
 This means exactly that every $h\in \mathcal O_X(X)$ can be written as $$h=\sum f_i\Phi_i$$ for some suitable global holomorphic functions $\Phi_i\in \mathcal O_X(X)$.

Comment: Indeed, that's quite an *"advanced level answer"* ;-) Anyway, +1, very nice!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words, @ComplexFlo.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* there's a proof that while $H(\Omega)$ is not a PID, nonetheless every finitely generated ideal is principal.